# Qt : Read a text file line by line in a specific time interval

Tags: qt, qt5, readline, qtextedit, qtextstream

I am trying to transfer the content of a text file to be displayed to the textEdit widget inside my GUI.

How can I make it display at the text edit one line at a time, instead of displaying all the content of the text file into the textEdit widget at one time?

By using "readLine" it can only display the first line of the text file content. How can I make it display the second line of the content after, let say 2 second?

Here's the sample of my code:

```
void ReadTextFile::on_pushButton_4_clicked() 
QFile textfile("my_file_here"); 
if (textfile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)||QIODevice::Text) { 
QTextStream in(&textfile); 
while (!in.atEnd()) { 
QString line = in.readLine(); 
ui->textEdit->append(line); 
} 
textfile.close();
 qDebug() <<"Close Text File"; 
} 
qDebug() <<"Out Pushbutton File"; 
}
```

I am a new guy learning Qt Programming, so please be gentle to me~~ ^^

Comment: Show us the code that reads the file using `readLine`. I think you close the stream after calling `readLine`, thus every time that code being executed, it always start from first line. Instead, you should not close the stream before reaching `EOF`.

Comment: void ReadTextFile::on_pushButton_4_clicked()

    QFile textfile("my_file_here");

if (textfile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)||QIODevice::Text)

{
QTextStream in(&textfile);

while (!in.atEnd())

{
QString line = in.readLine();

ui->textEdit->append(line);

       }
textfile.close();

qDebug() <<"Close Text File";

 }
qDebug() <<"Out Pushbutton File";

}

Comment: sorry I dont know how to use insert coding like as yours

Comment: Please edit the question and add your code in the question not in the comment. Format your code as explained in [https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks).

Comment: I think the question is already answered. In principle you need to use timer and remember the last line you've read.  If you just want to display line, you may use `setPlainText(QString &str)` instead of `append(QString &)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a timer to trigger reading of successive lines. This functionality is best separated into its own class that emits a signal each time a new line is available:

```
// https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/timed-read-44319722
#include <QtWidgets>

class PeriodicReader : public QObject {
   Q_OBJECT
   QTimer m_timer{this};
   QFile m_file{this};
   void readLine() {
      if (m_file.atEnd()) {
         m_timer.stop();
         return;
      }
      emit newLine(m_file.readLine());
   }
public:
   explicit PeriodicReader(QObject * parent = {}) : QObject(parent) {
      connect(&m_timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, &PeriodicReader::readLine);
   }
   void load(const QString & fileName) {
      m_file.close(); // allow re-opening of the file
      m_file.setFileName(fileName);
      if (m_file.open(QFile::ReadOnly | QFile::Text)) {
         readLine();
         m_timer.start(300); // 0.3s interval
      }
   }
   Q_SIGNAL void newLine(const QByteArray &);
};
```

Since we're using a `QPlainTextEdit` to display the text, we need to convert the raw lines into strings. We must remove any line endings since `QPlainTextEdit::appendPlainText` already adds a paragraph ending:

```
QString lineToString(QByteArray line) {
   while (line.endsWith('\n') || line.endsWith('\r'))
      line.chop(1);
   return QString::fromUtf8(line);
}
```

It's now a simple matter to put it together into a demo:

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
   QApplication app{argc, argv};

   QWidget window;
   QVBoxLayout layout{&window};
   QPushButton load{"Load"};
   QPlainTextEdit edit;
   layout.addWidget(&load);
   layout.addWidget(&edit);
   window.show();

   PeriodicReader reader;
   QObject::connect(&load, &QPushButton::clicked, [&]{
      auto name = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(&window);
      if (!name.isEmpty()) {
         edit.clear(); // allow re-opening of the file
         reader.load(name);
      }
   });
   QObject::connect(&reader, &PeriodicReader::newLine, &edit,
                    [&](const QByteArray & line){ edit.appendPlainText(lineToString(line)); });

   return app.exec();
}
#include "main.moc"
```

This concludes the complete example.

Comment: Thank you, sir! I have run the program and works well. 

But the code is a bit difficult for me to understand especially at line 16,17,33 and from 47 to 56 of the main.cpp file. But thanks for the aid! ^^

Comment: It's 2017 so we should be using modern C++11. Seems you have not kept up with it. **16** `{}` provides a default-constructed value, and for pointers is same as `nullptr`. In old days you'd write `0` or `NULL`. **17** This is the modern connect syntax. See Qt docs. **33** We create a string from UTF8 representation. A file by itself has no meaning, so we convert a stream of bytes to a string. **47-56** We connect the clicked signal to a lambda - a continuation object that captures references to the surrounding context. Lambdas bring back the Pascal local functions, and supercharge them :)

Comment: thank you, @KubaOber.

I was wondering if the text line that is read line by line can be inserted to Arduino as an input according to the sequence from the text file?

Answer (score 1):

You must create a `QTimer` to run the task every 2 seconds. To handle the text you can create a `QStringList` where you add each line with `readLine()`, the `atEnd` function will indicate that there is even data in the file.

```
QStringList texts;

QTimer *timer = new QTimer(this);

connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, [=](){
    if(!texts.isEmpty()){
        your_textEdit->append(texts.first());
        texts.pop_front();
    }
    else
        timer->stop();
});

QString fileName = "path_of_your_file"
QFile file(fileName);
if(file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
    QTextStream in(&file);
    while (!in.atEnd()) {
        texts.append(in.readLine());
    }
    timer->start(2000);
}
file.close();
```

The complete code is [here](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/TextEditExample).

Comment: Thank you @ eyllanesc,  I have tried your code , but when I tried to run the program it shows an error of 

" passing 'const QStringList' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive] "

at line   

"texts.pop_front(); " 

Where did I did wrong?

Comment: I have passed the link to the entire project, run it and tell me what you get, please.

Comment: I hae some problem with UI file. When I was double clicking the ui file inside the Qt creator to access it , a dialog box was shown. 

"An error has occurred while reading the UI file at line 35, column 98: Expected '=', but got '>' . "

Comment: @WanShahmisufiWanJamaludin You have tried my previous code, also if you want me to help you, you could create a new question explaining better and label me in it.